# Disable file digests in Sprockets compile task

Tags: ruby, rack, sprockets

**I am not using Rails.**

I'm using sprockets' built in compiler task **SprocketsTask**. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb#L8-L14).

I want to disable the file digests that are appended to each file. So *application-e7aa01ce5sdf9e6sdfdssd8sdfds8bb.css* will just become *application.css*.

There seems to be no documentation that I can find, and I've looked through the source quite a lot. I'm aware that I could remove the digest after the file has been created, but I thought i'd see if anyone had any better ideas first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

# Rakefile

```
require "sprockets"

assets = Sprockets::Environment.new
assets.append_path "app/assets/javascripts"

task :assets do
    assets["application.js"].write_to "output/assets"
end
```

$ rake assets

**with filters**

# Rakefile

```
require "sprockets"

assets = Sprockets::Environment.new
assets.append_path "app/assets/javascripts"
LOOSE_APP_ASSETS = lambda do |path, filename|
 filename !~ %r~app/assets~  && !%w[.js .css].include?(File.extname(path))
end
precompile = [LOOSE_APP_ASSETS, /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/]

task :assets do
    assets.each_logical_path(*precompile).each {|path|
        assets[path].write_to "output/assets/#{path}"
    }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was making it more complicated than I needed to!